# Find documents that contain certain field for sub-object MongoDb and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a collection with the following format:

```
[ 
  {
     firstname: 'Joe',
     lastname: 'Blow',
     emails: [
       {
          email: 'test@example.com',
          valid: false
       },
       {
          email: 'test2@example.com',
          valid: false
       }
     ],
     password: 'abc123',
     _id: 57017e173915101e0ad5d94a
  },
  {
     firstname: 'Johnny',
     lastname: 'Doe',
     emails: [
       {
          email: 'test3@example.com',
          valid: false
       }
     ],
     password: 'abc123',
     _id: 57017e173915101e0ad5d87b
  },
]
```

I am trying to find a user based on the `emails.email` field. Here is what I have so far:

```
db.collection('users').aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$emails"},
    {$group: {_id: "$_id",user_emails: { $push: "$emails.email" } } },
    {$match: {'user_emails': { $in: ['test@example.com'] } } }
  ], 
  (error, result) => {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(result);
  }
);
```

When I run this command in the mongo shell it seems to work; however when I run it in `Node.js` it prints `null` for the error and `[]` for the result.

What am I doing wrong? I am pretty new to `MongoDB` and just can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Not sure what the exact issue is, but if it's working in the mongo shell and not via node, then it probably has something to do with the driver you are using. Are you using mongoclient or mongoose to connect to mongo from nodejs?  Depending on what you're using, there may be slight differences in syntax between the drivers and the mongo shell.

Comment: @user2263572 I'm using an NPM package called [mongoConnect](https://github.com/hectorcorrea/mongoConnect) to connect to the database. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Most likely.  The mongodb documentation recommends you use mongoose which can be found here.  http://mongoosejs.com/.  I would highly recommend going that route.

Comment: @user2263572 How would I execute an operation like this with Mongoose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to unwind the entire emails? That will be a very expensive operation when your collection grows with tons of records.

The below query will return the user with the email test2@example.com. I think thats what you are looking for right?

```
db.email.find({emails :{$elemMatch:{email:"test2@example.com"}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have re-written your code with slight changes.

```
var col = db.collection('collection');
if (col) {
    col.aggregate([
        {$unwind: "$emails"},
        {$group: {_id: "$_id",user_emails: { $push: "$emails.email" } } },
        {$match: {'user_emails': { $in: ['test@example.com'] } } }
    ], function(e, r){
        if(e){
            console.log(error);
        }

        console.log(r);
        db.close();
    });
}
```

It should work, provided you have establish connection and other requirements successfully. Provided your sample documents, it will emit:

```
[
    {
        _id: '57017e173915101e0ad5d94a',
        user_emails: [
            'test@example.com',
            'test2@example.com'
        ]
    }
]
```