# Find documents that contain certain value for sub-object field Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

***Note***: I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36390877/find-documents-that-contain-certain-field-for-sub-object-mongodb-and-node-js/36392871), however at that time I was working purely with `MongoDB`, now I am trying to implement this with `Mongoose`. I decided it was appropriate to ask a separate question as I believe the answer will be fundamentally different, however please let me know if I was incorrect in that decision.

---

I have a collection with the following format:

```
[ 
  {
     firstname: 'Joe',
     lastname: 'Blow',
     emails: [
       {
          email: 'test@example.com',
          valid: false
       },
       {
          email: 'test2@example.com',
          valid: false
       }
     ],
     password: 'abc123',
     _id: 57017e173915101e0ad5d94a
  },
  {
     firstname: 'Johnny',
     lastname: 'Doe',
     emails: [
       {
          email: 'test3@example.com',
          valid: false
       }
     ],
     password: 'abc123',
     _id: 57017e173915101e0ad5d87b
  },
]
```

I am trying to find a user based on the `emails.email` field. Here is what I have so far:

```
UserModel.find()
         .where('emails')
         .elemMatch(function (elem) {
           elem.where('email').equals(userEmail);
         })
         .limit(1)
         .exec(
         (err, usersReturned) => {
           console.log('test2@example.com');
         });
```

What am I doing wrong? I am new to `Mongoose` and just can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do something like this :

```
UserModel.find({"emails.email": userEmail}).limit(1).exec(function(err, user){
    if(err) console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    else if(user) console.log("User Returned is : " + JSON.stringify(user));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mongodb `aggregate` function .Use `$unwind` on `"emails.email"` field and it will separate the array make as independent documents.

```
UserModel.aggregate( [
    { $unwind : "$emails" },
    { $match: {$emails.email:"email you want to put"}}
],function(err,result){    
    //write code but you want to do
});
```